# If Words Match, Replace nth Field Only

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop, text

So I have a code that I want to make that:

if UniqueID from file1 = UniqueID from file2:

replace the nth field for UniqueID file1

Example Data:

Names:

**Too** Boo Moo Moo Soo Choo

Poo Boo Moo Moo Soo Choo

Koo Boo Loo Moo Soo Choo

**Ooo** Boo Poo Moo Soo Choo

OtherNames:

IIo Boo Moo Moo Soo Choo

**Too** Boo ROO Moo Fuc Choo

**Ooo** Boo YOO Moo Soo Choo

WANTED final result:

**Too** Boo NEW Moo Soo Choo

Poo Boo Moo Moo Soo Choo

Koo Boo Loo Moo Soo Choo

**Ooo** Boo NEW Moo Soo Choo

```
infile = path
filename = "Names.txt"

otherin = path
othfile = "OtherNames.txt"

otherpth = os.path.join(otherin,othfile)
path = os.path.join(infile,filename)

mop = open(otherpth,"r")
rdmo = mop.readlines()
L = list(rdmo)

doc = open(path,"r")
doc2 = doc.readlines()
k = list(doc2)

for words in k:
    wordsplit = words.split(" ")
    first = wordsplit[0]
    sec = wordsplit[1]
    third = wordsplit[2]
    fourth = wordsplit[3]
    fifth = wordsplit[4]
    sixth = wordsplit[5]
    allwords = first +" "+ sec +" "+ third +" "+ fourth +" "+ fifth+" "+sixth

    for entry in L:
        entsplit = entry.split(" ")
        a = entsplit[0]
        b = entsplit[1]
        c = entsplit[2]
        d = entsplit[3]
        e = entsplit[4]
        f = entsplit[5].replace("\n","")
        mtch = a +" "+ b+" "+ c+" "+ d+" "+ e+" "+f

        if first == a:
            newword = allwords[:8]+"NEW "+allwords[12:]

            final = path
            text = "NamesFinal.txt"
            finaltext = os.path.join(final,text)
            docfinal = open(finaltext,"w")

            for lines in doc2:
                G = lines.replace(allwords,newword)
                docfinal.write(G)
```

Currently, it just spits out the last loop of Ooo.  When again, I want it to spit out the Names text file, except with those fields changed to New.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want "Ooo Boo YOO Moo Soo Choo" in the output?

Comment: Nope don't want it.  I just want the 3rd item replaced with NEW for those that match.  Sorry if that was confusing since the one has NEW in it.

Answer (score 1):

Every line that matches will have a "NEW" in the third column

```
import csv

with open('path/to/names') as infile:
    db1 = {}
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' '):
        db1[row[0]] = row

with open('path/to/otherNames') as infile:
    db2 = set()
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' '):
        db2.add(row[0])

for k in db1:
    if k in db2:
        db1[k][2] = "NEW"

with open('path/to/names') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' '):
        k = line[0]
        writer.writerow(db1[k])
```

Comment: Nope, no YOO, sorry for the confusion.  I want NEW in there.

Comment: @JoshClayton: done! Everything that matches will now be replaced with "NEW"